# Cannot Delete Text from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a problem. I try to delete items from an array but after deletion when I rebuild the project I still saw my deleted items on screen.

Here is my code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "PasswordModel", in: managedContext)!
    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
    
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        self.passwordList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        
        managedContext.delete(item)
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        }catch let saveErr {
            print("Failed to delete password", saveErr)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I save this deletion to my Core Data?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your print statement print any error? As long as your `managedContext.parent` is `nil` saving the context should save to disk. Can you also post the code where you are creating and loading the persistence container?

Comment: You are always creating a new object in that function, `NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)`, why??? You should get the object to delete from the array instead.

Comment: Hi, @JoakimDanielson I just copied this part from my other code which is add items to list. What should I use instead of this part?

Comment: Hi, @user1046037 unfortunately there is no error.

Comment: I think I said that in my previous comment. Don’t create a new object, get the object to delete from the array since just removing it from the array isn’t enough

Comment: Yes, I saw it after your edit. I'm very fresh. Just six or seven days with Swift. Sorry for that but I don't understand what should I write.

Comment: As Joakim has suggested, you need to delete something that already exists, what you are doing is creating something new and then deleting it, so you don't see any difference after deleting it. Look for a function `cellForRow(at:)` that is responsible for displaying the cell, that should give you a clue as to what you need to delete.

Comment: IMHO it is better to spend some time learning the basics of UIKit and Core data before building / debugging apps.

Comment: Ah thanks for your help @user1046037 I just try to learn basics with building apps. So maybe it can not be true way. :/

Comment: btw @user1046037 u can find this projects code at https://github.com/miracdogan/RandomPasswordGenerator

Comment: Now says: No exact matches in call to subscript when I use your answer.
And thanks for your advice.